# Need to "grep" multiple output

Tags: shell, ubuntu, sed, grep, battery

Using this command (`upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT1`) my terminal show the following output:

```
  native-path:          BAT1
  vendor:               LG
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              mar 31 may 2016 12:45:15 CEST (101 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               fully-charged
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              50,4088 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         51,4522 Wh
    energy-full-design:  48,1 Wh
    energy-rate:         6,29 W
    voltage:             8,313 V
    percentage:          97%
    capacity:            100%
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charged-symbolic'
```

I need to obtain an array with the data of the output. Something like this: `[BAT1, LG, yes, [...], 100%, 'battery-full-charged-symbolic']`

Any way to do it?

Comment: Do you mean a Bash array?

Answer (score 0):

your output is typical column-based text. (delimiter is `:`). You can use awk to format it into your desired format.

```
upower cmd...|awk -F':\\s*' '{printf "%s%s",(NR==1?"[":", "), $2}END{print "]"}'
```

Will give you:

```
[BAT1, LG, yes, mar 31 may 2016 12, yes, yes, , yes, yes, fully-charged, none, 50,4088 Wh, 0 Wh, 51,4522 Wh, 48,1 Wh, 6,29 W, 8,313 V, 97%, 100%, 'battery-full-charged-symbolic']
```

Comment: Oh, now it works. But what I really want is to store all this output with an array. Is possible?

Comment: I don't know which context are you talking about the "array". it gives just the same output format as you required.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like :

```
 var = ( $(upowerOutput | grep -oE ':.+$' | sed -e 's/^[ \t:]*//') )
```

The `grep` part fetches the required fields and `sed` is used to trim the leading spaces and `:`.